# Should I add the Acknowledgement in the pre-final version of a (PhD) thesis already? Or wait after I got the feedback from my supervisor?

Tags: phd, thesis, acknowledgement

Should I add the Acknowledgement in the pre-final version of a (PhD) thesis for proofreading already? Or wait after I got the feedback from my supervisor?

Comment: Why do you think it matters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do whatever you want -- it doesn't matter unless you plan on saying something negative about anyone in there (which I would advise against :-) ) nobody cares what is or isn't in the pre-final version.

On a broader level, the fact that you worry about this sort of issue *and take the time to write a StackExchange question about it* means that you need to learn to separate the issues in your life that matter and those that don't. There are plenty of things that deserve your brain power. This is not one of them, but spending time and energy on it means that the things that deserve it do not receive it.

Comment: Maybe if he/she reads how thankful I am for their feedback then they maybe make less effort since they know, I am already maximum thankful ...

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Not worth thinking too hard about.

Comment: @user3352632  You are *supposed* to thank your supervisor.  Quit worrying about it.  And remember, it is your supervisor's job to see that you graduate, not to cause you trouble.

Comment: thanks @WolfgangBangerth, in general you are right, I probably overthinking this. But I am not sure what is the norm and dont want to step into trouble.

Comment: @BobBrown - ok, thats right. I am thanking as much and as hard as I can!